# Is it possible to install a custom keyboard layout created on Windows?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I recently switched back to Ubuntu after using Windows for a while. While I was using Windows, I created a custom keyboard layout using [Microsoft's official keyboard layout creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339). I've set it all up to suit my needs and have added a lot to it, and now after switching I would like to use the same layout on Ubuntu. I'm wondering if it is possible to convert this layout for use on Ubuntu, as remaking the layout would take quite a while. If that is not possible, that's what I'll have to do but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Probably not possible. Take a look at e.g. the US layouts in the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file, and compare it with the file(s) from Windows. You can pick a standard keyboard layout which is as close to your current one as possible and create a custom layout out of that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was afraid that was the case. Looks like I will have to recreate it after all.